# Rewriting Python Classes to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have some python classes written and being constructed like this:

```
class Customer:
def __init__(self, name, full_name, gender, age, instruments, paid):
    self.name = name
    self.full_name = full_name
    self.gender= gender
    self.age= age
    self.instruments= instruments
    self.paid= paid

list = []

list.append( Customer('Customer1', 'First Customer', 'Male', 26, ["Guitar", "Bass"], [100, 200]))
list.append( Customer('Customer2', 'Second Customer', 'Female', 24, ["Drums", "Bass"], [150, 230]))
```

I'm trying to rewrite my functions from python to JavaScript, and having some problems/doubts  about this data structure.

The instruments and paid values(only example here) can be text values or numbers. When I access it and select "Customer 1" I should be able to choose the instrument to print the paid price

How do I write the same structure in JavaScript?

All this is that I am trying to change this personal python file to a customer local .html page.

Maybe JavaScript is not the best here and, since i am not proficient on that, I can spent some time in other language to handle it.

How would I write it in .js or, what would be the better option to go with local .html

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Comment: Yes, my main problem is how to write the same class style as an array in JavaScript

Comment: I dont really understand your question, what do you mean by """but when i access it, when go "Customer 1" and select "bass" give me "200""""? do you have a JS example that does not work? could you share it with us?

Comment: Nothing in js at this moment. 
Actually, i have the whole program in python. 

I call a numbered list via console to select the customer. 
Once selected i go over another list to select the instrument
Once selected it, the console shows me the paid price

Comment: I don't have a JS example because I was not able to construct anything.

Comment: While the problem in the question is real, StackOverflow is not well suited for tutoring in different programming languages. I suggest you become a better JavaScript programmer first by studying the basic language structure in online courses, tutorials and books, as other people cannot do the thinking for you.

Comment: I understand that Mikko. But you are just telling this, because I explained the problem. If I just wrote "How to rewrite this" everything would be fine as many other questions.

Comment: I think you should start by designing your solution first and then ask something more spetific. JS has clases and objects equal to python, but if you want to see your software in a HTML document then you have to interface the result of your JS to the DOM which is something completely different. In python you have direct access to the shell. So one thing is the logic and another complely different is how the result of this logic will be shown to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

If you glance at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

you could end up with

```js
class Customer {
  constructor(name, full_name, gender, age, instruments, paid) {
    this.name = name
    this.full_name = full_name
    this.gender = gender
    this.age = age
    this.instruments = instruments
    this.paid = paid
  }
}
list = []

list.push(new Customer('Customer1', 'First Customer', 'Male', 26, ["Guitar", "Bass"], [100, 200]))
list.push(new Customer('Customer2', 'Second Customer', 'Female', 24, ["Drums", "Bass"], [150, 230]))
console.log(list)
```